# How to group and average fields from JPA repo and put into new collection using java streams

Tags: java, jpa, repository, grouping, java-stream

I need to calculate average occupancy for selected day of week (eg. all Fridays - for each minute). I didn't find any JPQL/Querydsl solution for this problem because of lack of Date/Time functions. So I'm trying to make use of Java Streams. My (simplified) object:

```
class Occupancy {
   private LocalDateTime timeStamp;
   private int occupied;
}
```

my repo:

```
@Query("select o from Occupancy o")
public Stream<Occupancy> streamAllOccupancies();
```

sample:

```
try ( Stream<Occupancy> stream = repository.streamAllOccupancies()) {

   Function<Occupancy,LocalTime> OccupancyMinutesGrouping = (Occupancy o) -> {
        return o.getDateTime().toLocalTime().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
   };


   Map<LocalTime,Double> avgMap = stream
      .filter( o -> o.getDateTime().getDayOfWeek() == DayOfWeek.MONDAY) //example
         .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
               OccupancyMinutesGrouping, 
               Collectors.averagingInt(Occupancy::getOccupied)
            )
         );
}
```

It works - but is it possible change this map into list of my occupancy objects:

```
new Occupancy( localTime, averagedOccupancy );
```

I'm also worried about stream efficiency - it has to process all records from the database. How does the stream work with jpa repo? First SQL gets all the records - then stream processes it? Or are they processed sequentially on every record? Maybe the best solution is to use Native SQL query insted of Stream? Any ideas will be very helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for conversion to the `List<Occupancy>`, please note that `occupied` field is of `int` type while average could be non-integral. So I assume that the `Occupancy` class is defined this way:

```
class Occupancy {
   private LocalDateTime timeStamp;
   private double occupied;

   public Occupancy(LocalDateTime ts, double occ) {
       this.timeStamp = ts;
       this.occupied = occ;
   }
}
```

Now you can just create one more stream from the resulting map:

```
List<Occupancy> occupancies = avgMap.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> new Occupancy(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It seems that intermediate `Map` is unavoidable (at least if your stream is not already sorted by `LocalTime`).

As for memory usage: it depends on the underlying JDBC driver. The resulting stream indeed reads the underlying `ResultSet` row-by-row, but it's JDBC-specific how many rows are prebuffered at once. For example, it's known that MySQL driver by default retrieves complete `ResultSet` into the memory, so you may need some query hint like this:

```
@QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "" + Integer.MIN_VALUE))
```

See [this blog post](http://knes1.github.io/blog/2015/2015-10-19-streaming-mysql-results-using-java8-streams-and-spring-data.html) for details.

Also note that if your JDBC driver actually fetches the data row-by-row from the server (without buffering), this actually might have worse performance as you may need more round-trips between DBMS and your application (this might be especially crucial if DBMS server is located on different machine). So consult your JDBC driver documentation for additional details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Of course solution with the second stream works, however I thought about using only one stream and group->average and then put the results into list. I'm using H2 in development - but in prod. it will be MySQL. Thank you for the tip.